# Input value onchange does not remove error class

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, form-submit, jquery-events

I have form with some inputs `Adults` and `child`. When I select the values of Adults and child maximum than required and I have logic to display error message. If I change values to less than required (`Using onchange`) the error message does not go away.

I am able to check while submitting values. My code is working for submit function and having issue while onchange the input of Adults and child. The error message still remains.

Should onchange function inside submit function?

```
   noLink : function() {
            $('.nolink').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        },

var $adultsInput = $('#bookingAdultCount'),
    $childrenInput = $('#bookingChildrenCount'),
    $bookingError = $('#booking-error'),
    $bookingForm = $('#bookingWidgetForm'),

  $bookingForm.submit(function(event) {
              // logic for submit 
        });

 // onchange event that does not work
  $adultsInput.on('change', function() {
       $adultsInput.parent().removeClass('booking-error');
       $childrenInput.parent().removeClass('booking-error');
  });
```

---

```
    <div class="filter__options-wrapper__filter-option">     
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="bookingAdultCount" class="initGrow doNotClose" name="Adults" placeholder="Adults" min="1" max="10" readonly>
        </div>

  <ul class="filter__option__guests-list growMe filter__options-wrapper__single-choice-list open">
    <li><a class="nolink" href="#0" data-value="1" data-input-target="bookingAdultCount">1 Adult</a></li>
    <li><a class="nolink" href="#0" data-value="2" data-input-target="bookingAdultCount">2 Adults</a></li>
    <li><a class="nolink" href="#0" data-value="3" data-input-target="bookingAdultCount">3 Adults</a></li>
    <li><a class="nolink" href="#0" data-value="4" data-input-target="bookingAdultCount">4 Adults</a></li>
    <li><a class="nolink" href="#0" data-value="5" data-input-target="bookingAdultCount">5 Adults</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: According to your code the input is `readonly`, I assume the value of the input is changed with the `<a>` elements listed bellow, can you show us the code of those buttons? The `change` event is usually fired from direct actions of the user, you are probably changing the value programatically, thus not triggering the event.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is because `change` and `input` events aren't fired when you set the value of an input in JavaScript (which I presume you are doing by way of the `<a class="nolink"....>`.

Here is some code to demonstrate:

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var btn = document.getElementById('changeval');
//use input instead of change to demonstrate. Input is the same as change except for every character added to the text field.
test.addEventListener('input', (evt) => { console.log(evt.target.value); });

btn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  test.value += "a";
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='test' value='' />
<button id='changeval'>Change Value</button>
```

You will have to move your `change` logic to wherever you are handling the click events for those links.

FYI, The reason for this behavior, I believe, is if you were to change the value of the field in javascript, inside the change event listener for that very field, you would cause an infinite loop. So browser vendors don't expose the change event if the change source was JS (because you can just move all relevant logic to the place where you were setting that value anyhow).

Comment: I have added nolink click event handler function in code.